# Re-plot graph as a video

Tags: python, r, animation, video, plot

I have a dataset which needs to be re- plotted in real time as a video. There are 1000 data points in 1 second. After this, I would also like to replot the same video 1/10th of the speed. An example is shown below. I did this in another software, which had an option for doing this in a GUI interface.

[image: Actual signal in real time]

[image: Slowed down graph - 1/10th speed of actual signal]

Is there a way to do this in R or Python? I looked into some libraries like ‘animation’ in R but could not get exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example in R using the `animation` package:

```
library(animation)

set.seed(2)
dat = data.frame(x=1:50, y=cumsum(rnorm(50)))

# Two times through the animation, once fast, once slow
ani.options(interval=rep(c(1/nrow(dat),1/nrow(dat)*10), each=nrow(dat)))

saveGIF(for(i in 1:(2*nrow(dat))) {
  plot(dat$x[1:(i %% nrow(dat))], dat$y[1:(i %% nrow(dat))], type="l", 
       ylim=range(dat$y), xlim=range(dat$x), xlab="Time", ylab="Value")
}, "my_movie.gif")
```

[image]

Comment: That was really helpful - I have questions about the ani.options argument. When it is set at 0.02 and the number of data points is 50, it should plot the whole graph in 50*0.02, i.e 1s, which it does. I tried for 0.04, 0.06 etc and it works accordingly. But when I try setting it at 0.001, it should plot the whole graph in 50*0.001, i.e 0.05 s right?  It takes 5 s instead. For my graphs, I would like to plot a data point every 0.001s and I have data for about 10 s in real time.

Comment: I'm not sure. It might be limited by how quickly the computer can display the frames of the GIF.

Comment: I tried saving it as a video instead of gif and it worked. I guess there is some limitation with gif

Comment: Hello! I am getting back to this after sometime. I am now getting an error:Error in magick_image_animate(image, delay, as.integer(loop), dispose) : 
  Expecting a single value: [extent=100]. What could be the reason for it? I am posting this as a new question as well!